# Wordpress NGINX Log error: "directory index of [Folder] is forbidden"

Tags: wordpress, nginx

We're having this error continously on our NGINX server with a wordpress site, I'm not entirely sure why it's even being attempted to be indexed.. I'm not entirely sure what to do with that one, how can I stop NGINX from trying to index that?

```
2023/06/14 20:58:05 [error] 17653#17653: *4736496 directory index of "tryhealingmusic.com/htdocs/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/" is forbidden, client: 143.244.38.134, server: domain.com, request: "GET /wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/ HTTP/2.0", host: tryhealingmusic.com", referrer: "https://tryhealingmusic.b-cdn.net/wp-content/cache/min/1/82717fb7c37467a25bb6834e35763ecb.css"
```

I've tried to set up redirects, purge all caches, update the plugins etc, and can't seem to make it go away.